# How to distinct specific column after union of two different tables?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I want to union two different tables and make it unique for specific column. I am using postgresql database.

```
q1 = self.dbsession.query(
            A.id.label('a_id'),
            null().label('b_id'),
            A.name.label('name'),
            A.email.label('email'),
            A.photo.label('photo'))

q2 = self.dbsession.query(
            B.matched_a_id.label('a_id'),
            B.id.label('b_id'),
            B.name.label('name'),
            B.email.label('email'),
            A.photo.label('photo'))

q1.union(q2).all()
```

This is output which I get:

`[(306, 80, 'StackOverFlow', 'stack@over.flow', 'www.picture.url'), (306, None, 'StackOverFlow', 'stack@over.flow', 'www.picture.url'), (305, None, 'Google', 'google@gmail.com', ''), (None, 82, 'Explorer', 'explorer@microsoft.com', '')`

As you can see first and second item is almost duplicated. I would like to distinct all records after union with first column which is labeled as `a_id`. Is it possible?

Expected output will be for me, the same list but without item which has identical first column as another one and second column is None, for example:
`[(306, 80, 'StackOverFlow', 'stack@over.flow', 'www.picture.url'), (305, None, 'Google', 'google@gmail.com', ''), (None, 82, 'Explorer', 'explorer@microsoft.com', '')`

Comment: What do you mean by "distinct all records after union with first column"? Do you wish to discard results based on some criteria, keeping only the first / last / nth?

Comment: Please show sample input and the expected output.

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes exactly. As you can see first and second item in output is almost the same. So as output I would expect list without one of that items. For example where first columns are the same and second column is None. Am I more clear now?

Comment: Maybe you're after something like order by `b_id`, nulls last, and then pick the 1st in a group (by `a_id`). The solution to that is DBMS specific, so please include what database system you're using. But perhaps the better question is: what question is the query meant to answer, or what are you trying to query?

Comment: @IljaEverilä I am using postgresql database. Let say Table A is Users and Table B is ApplicationInvitation. I want to have union table for people which are already users and for those who are invited. So when person become User, I don't want to count it also as a Invitation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added expected output.

Comment: More than one way to skin a cat: you could exclude invitations of existing users in the latter query using NOT EXISTS.

Comment: @IljaEverilä can you show me how to skin that cat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution was actually easy..

```
users = self.dbsession.query(
        User.id.label('a_id'),
        null().label('b_id'),
        User.name.label('name'),
        User.email.label('email'),
        User.photo.label('photo'))

invitations = self.dbsession.query(
        ApplicationInvitation.matched_user_id.label('a_id'),
        ApplicationInvitation.id.label('b_id'),
        ApplicationInvitation.name.label('name'),
        ApplicationInvitation.email.label('email'),
        User.photo.label('photo')).\
    filter(ApplicationInvitation.matched_user_id.is(None)).\
    outerjoin(User, ApplicationInvitation.matched_user_id == User.id)

users.union(invitations).all()
```